# Mobile optimized checkout for PayPal Website Payments Standard

Tags: mobile, paypal

How can I get the "mobile optimized checkout experience" to work as described by PayPal on their Mobile Website Payments Standard page https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-website-payments-standard?

The docs say if you have a BuyNow button without any fancy options, when a user on a mobile device clicks it, it should send them to a mobile optimized checkout experience. However, all I get is the same PayPal checkout page that one gets on a desktop browser. My simple button code looks like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="name@domain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Am I missing something here or is PayPal just screwing up here? This seems like the most fundamental thing they could do to help support mobile payments. I don't want to mess with their Express Checkout stuff or any of their APIs. I just want the standard BuyNow buttons to "do the right thing" on a mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating your example with an email address other than name@domain.com. I used your code exactly as is with email=seller@designerfotos.com (an example email PayPal uses for sample buttons) and it worked just fine. Went into the mobile optimized website payments standard experience.

Also, make sure your account (email address) that you're testing with doesn't have any shipping and tax rules defined in the profile settings. These are marked as currently unsupported at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-website-payments-standard. You can pass in shipping and tax values as button parameters and those should work.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: One additional thing I'd like to point out with regards to the shipping / tax calculator / other advanced parameters (such as 'options'): "These are marked as currently unsupported". Note the *currently*.

Comment: I had the email in the code example anonymous on purpose. :) I did go in an remove all shipping and tax rules and that did the trick. Thanks for the pointer!