# Paypal payments standard with mobile optimized checkout

Tags: mobile, paypal

I am running a Django app that is hooked up to paypal payments standard and that generates encrypted 'Buy Now' buttons. Everything works as it should on desktop, but when I use a mobile device (android and IOS), I do not get sent to the mobile optimized checkout page.

If I go to [this non-encrypted test page](https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=bacon@example.com&item_name=Bacon&amount=5), I actually get the mobile checkout page. As soon as I change that fake business email to my real one, I only get the desktop page.

This leads me to believe I have some kind of configuration issues in my merchant account, as opposed to an issue with encrypted buttons.

I looked at the documentation on [x.com](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard#usecases). They mention that the mobile checkout page is not compatible with these use cases:

- Instant Update API
- Buyer Supplied Price, Desc, Qty
- Profile Based Shipping & Tax Discounts
- Payment Type: Auth, Order
- Inventory Management

I originally had shipping rules, so I deleted those. I don't think I have any of the other things enabled, but its hard to tell seeing as these unsupported use cases are really vague. I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538548/mobile-optimized-checkout-for-paypal-website-payments-standard) SO post, and I have disabled my tax rules, but it did not fix the issue for me.

Does anyone have experience with this? Is there a way to force the mobile version of the checkout page, using paypal payments standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this by implementing their Express Checkout flow.

Don't believe their documentation. Express Checkout can do EXACTLY what paypal payments standard can do, and the API has nice features like forcing the non-paypal account pane to open by default.

Comment: Here is a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087146/using-paypal-express-checkout-from-jquery