# Paypal can't detect mobile devices on checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout, paypal-buttons

I'm using PayPal Payments Standard. On the [x.com](http://x.com) it says:

> Mobile PayPal Payments Standard (MPPS) is based on PayPal Payments
> Standard (PPS). PPS the easiest way to integrate a PayPal payment flow
> into a website, and once integrated into a website, the mobile
> **functionality is automatically provided** for users who access your
> website using a mobile device.

Everything is working on the checkout but it's always the PC version. Tried with iOS and Android phones, BlueStacks emulator and different User Agent settings from Chrome's Developer Tool. Neither works.

This is my button:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal_form">
    <!-- Things you should change on per order -->
    
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$paypalItemName?>"> <!-- Description of goods -->
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$total_amount?>"> <!-- Amount to bill customer -->
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?=$paypalID?>"> <!-- Unique sales ID number -->
     
    <!-- Things you only need to change on setup -->
    
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="name@mydomain.com">   <!-- Master Paypal Email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> <!-- Currency -->
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/order-success.php?ppl=1&subscription_id=<?php echo $paypalID; ?>"> <!-- Your thank you page -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/order-declined.php">  <!-- Page incase of error-->

    <!-- Things you should not change -->
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1"> <!-- Quantity - Keep One -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1"> <!-- Item Number-->
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8"> <!-- Leave as is -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"> <!-- No note required by customer -->
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.mydomain.com/api/paypal.php"> <!--Leave as is-->
    
    <input type="image" src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

With `cmd="_express-checkout"` version I can change it to `cmd="_express-checkout-mobile"` on my form but there is not an option like that for `cmd="_xclick"`.

So, should I implement `Exrepess Checkout` for mobile devices or there is a way to achieve this with PayPal Payments Standard?

**Possible duplicate:** [Mobile optimized checkout for PayPal Website Payments Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538548/mobile-optimized-checkout-for-paypal-website-payments-standard)
On the accepted answer there it says to check the email. I haven't access to it but I tried with my personal email which has not any additional settings for shipping tax and tax rules set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are buidling a page specifically for mobile, then I would suggest using the Express Checkout for mobile.  However, if you are wanting to use Website Payments Standard, there is not code to specifically direct the buyer through a mobile flow.  The PayPal pages will pick up that it is a mobile device and direct the buyer through the mobile flow.  However, this will not always be the case.  There are certain things that can cause the buyer to go through the reqular web flow instead of the mobile flow even if they are on a mobile device.  This can happen depending on what type of button they are using, or what variables are being passed over in the code, as all variables are not supported by the mobile flow.